# Sort a list based on values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Is my approach here the right way to do it in Python?  As I'm new to Python, I appreciate any feedback you can provide, especially if I'm way off here.

My task is to order a list of file names based on values from a dataset.  Specifically, these are file names that I need to sort based on site information.  The resulting list is the order in which the reports will be printed.

**Site Information**

```
key_info = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_id': ['1010','3030','2020','5050','4040','4040']
    , 'key_name': ['Name_A','Name_B','Name_C','Name_D','Name_E','Name_E']
    , 'key_value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]
})
key_info = key_info[['key_id','key_name']].drop_duplicates()
key_info['key_id'] = key_info.key_id.astype('str').astype('int64')
```

**Filenames**

These are the file names I need to sort.  In this example, I sort by just the key_id, but I assume I could easily add a column to site information and sort it by that as well.

```
filenames = ['1010_Filename','2020_Filename','3030_Filename','5050_Filename','4040_Filename']
```

**Sorting**

The resulting "filenames" is the final sorted list.

```
names_df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': filenames})
names_df['key_id'] = names_df.filename.str[:4].astype('str').astype('int64')

merged_df = pd.merge(key_info, names_df, on='key_id', how='right')
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values('key_id')

filenames = merged_df['filename'].tolist()
```

I'm looking for any solutions that might be better or more Pythonic.  Or, if there is a more appropriate place to post "code review" questions.

Comment: Are you required to use Pandas or will any collection be fine?

Comment: Pandas is not required.  If it makes any difference, "Site information is coming in as a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your use of Pandas, but it isn't the most Pythonic as it uses data structures that are a superset of Python. Nevertheless, I think we can improve on what you have. I will show an improved version and I will show a completely native Python way to do it. Either is fine I suppose?

The strictly Python version is best for people who do know Pandas as there's a large learning curve associated with that.

**Common**

For both examples, let's assume a function like this:

```
def trim_filenames(filename):
    return filename[0:4]
```

I use this in both examples.

**Improvements**

```
# Load the DataFrame and give it a proper index (I added some data)
key_info = pd.DataFrame(index=['2020','5050','4040','4040','6000','7000','1010','3030'], data={'key_name':['Name_C','Name_D','Name_E','Name_E','Name_F','Name_G','Name_A','Name_B'], 'key_value' :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
# Eliminate duplicates and sort in one step
key_info = key_info.groupby(key_info.index).first()

filenames = ['1010_Filename','2020_Filename','3030_Filename','5050_Filename','4040_Filename']
names_df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': filenames})
# Let's give this an index too so we can match on the index (not the function call)
names_df.index=names_df.filename.transform(trim_filenames)
combined = pd.concat([key_info,names_df], axis=1)
```

combined matches by index, but there are some keys with no filenames. It looks like this now:

```
     key_name  key_value       filename
1010   Name_A          7  1010_Filename
2020   Name_C          1  2020_Filename
3030   Name_B          8  3030_Filename
4040   Name_E          3  4040_Filename
5050   Name_D          2  5050_Filename
6000   Name_F          5            NaN
7000   Name_G          6            NaN
```

Now we drop the NaN columns and create the list of filenames:

```
combined.filename.dropna().values.tolist()
['1010_Filename', '2020_Filename', '3030_Filename', '4040_Filename', '5050_Filename']
```

**Python Only Version** (no framework)

```
key_info = {'2020' : {'key_name':'Name_C', 'key_value':1},'5050' : {'key_name':'Name_D', 'key_value':2},'4040' : {'key_name':'Name_E', 'key_value':3},'4040' : {'key_name':'Name_E', 'key_value':4},'6000' : {'key_name':'Name_F', 'key_value':5},'7000' : {'key_name':'Name_G', 'key_value':6},'1010' : {'key_name':'Name_A', 'key_value':7},'3030' : {'key_name':'Name_B', 'key_value':8}}
filenames = ['1010_Filename','2020_Filename','3030_Filename','5050_Filename','4040_Filename']

# Let's get a dictionary of filenames that is keyed by the same key as in key_info:
hashed_filenames = {}
for filename in filenames:
  # Note here I'm using the function again
  hashed_filenames[trim_filenames(filename)] = filename

# We'll store the new filenames in new_filenames:
new_filenames = []

# sort the key info and loop it
for key in sorted(key_info.keys()):
  # for each key, if the key matches in the hashed_filenames, then add it to the list
  if key in hashed_filenames:
    new_filenames.append(hashed_filenames[key])
```

**Summary**

Both solutions are concise, and I like Pandas, but I like better something that is immediately readable by anyone that knows Python. The Python only solution (of course, they are both Python) is the one you should go with, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
out_list = []
for x in key_info.key_id:
    for f in filenames:
        if str(x) in f:
            out_list.append(f)


out_list
['1010_Filename', '3030_Filename', '2020_Filename', '5050_Filename', '4040_Filename']
```